# Split number into several numbers

Tags: java

I wrote a programm to get the cross sum of  a number:

So when i type in 3457 for example it should output 3 + 4 + 5 + 7. But somehow my logik wont work. When i type in 68768 for example i get 6 + 0 + 7. But when i type in 97999 i get the correct output 9 + 7 + 9. I know that i have could do this task easily with diffrent methods but i tried to use loops . Here is my code: And thanks to all

```
import Prog1Tools.IOTools;

public class Aufgabe {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.print("Please type in a number: ");
        int zahl = IOTools.readInteger();

        int ten_thousand = 0;
        int thousand = 0;
        int hundret = 0;


        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            if((zahl / 10000) == i){
                ten_thousand = i;
                zahl = zahl - (ten_thousand * 10000);
            }

            for(int f = 0; f < 10; f++){
                if((zahl / 1000) == f){
                    thousand = f;
                    zahl = zahl - (thousand * 1000);
                }

                for(int z = 0; z < 10; z++){
                    if((zahl / 100) == z){
                        hundret = z;
                    }
                }


            }
        }
            System.out.println( ten_thousand + " + " + thousand + " + " + hundret);
    }
}
```

Comment: What should be the output for `9999`? Do you want to ignore duplicate numbers?

Comment: @JohnSmith why dont you just convert it to string and traverse each character of string?

Comment: how do you mean cross sum? don't get why 97999 i get the correct output 9 + 7 + 9 is correct. Is the sum of different numbers?

Comment: @Apostlos im learning java and i tried to fullfill the task in my book

Comment: @X-Pippes i would ask that too. it doesnt make sense...

Comment: Ok with cross sum i mean 2 + 4 + 6 = 12 for 246 but in this code example i only go from ten thousands to hundrets! The ouput of 9999 should be 9 +9 +9 +9

Comment: If 9999 should = 9 + 9 + 9 + 9, then why should 97999 = 9 + 7 + 9? What is your actual requirement?

Comment: If you want to use you method of loops, for practice, then you should not nest them. Do the ten thousand loop. Then move on to a thousand loop. And so on. In terms of code, remove two braces before the System.out... and move each to the first and second loop respectively. More important, use a debugger. That way, you can step through your code and see exactly where it flows, and compare that to where you think it ought to flow. 
Since Java has a "%" operator, you do not need your loops, but since this an exercise, I've addressed your way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the code you've presented is that you have the inner loops nested.  Instead, you should finish iterating over each loop before starting with the next one.

What's happening at the moment with 68768 is when the outer for loop gets to i=6, the ten_thousand term gets set to 6 and the inner loops proceed to the calculation of the 'thousand' and 'hundred' terms - and does set those as you expect (and leaving zahl equal to 768 - notice that you don't decrease zahl at the hundreds stage)

But then the outer loop continues looping, this time with i=7.  With zahl=768, zahl/1000 = 0' so the 'thousand' term gets set to 0.  The hundred term always gets reset to 7 with zahl=768.

The 97999 works because the thousand term is set on the final iteration of the 'i' loop, so never gets reset.

The remedy is to not nest the inner loops - and it'll perform a lot better too!

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
String s = Integer.toString(zahl);
for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
    System.out.println(s.charAt(i) + " + ");
}
System.out.println(s.charAt(s.length()-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this

```
input  =  56789;

int sum = 0;

int remainder = input % 10  // = 9;
sum += remainder  // now sum is sum + remainder
input /= 10;  // this makes the input 5678

...
// repeat the process
```

To loop it, use a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop.  This a great example of when to use a `while` loop.  If this is for a class, it will show your understanding of when to use `while` loops: when the number of iterations is unknown, but is based on a condition.

```
int sum = 0;
while (input/10 != 0) {
    int remainder = input % 10;
    sum += remainder;
    input /= 10;
}
// this is all you really need
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sample is a little bit complicated. To extract the tenthousand, thousand and the hundreds you can simply do this:

```
private void testFunction(int zahl) {
    int tenThousand = (zahl / 10000) % 10;
    int thousand = (zahl / 1000) % 10;
    int hundred = (zahl / 100) % 10;
    System.out.println(tenThousand + "+" + thousand + "+" + hundred);
}
```

Bit as many devs reported you should convert it to string and process character by character.